# How to remove NA and missing values(blank) from a CSV file and replace them as 0

Tags: r

How to remove NA and missing values(blank) from a CSV file and replace them as 0
I tried the following but not working

```
moviedata = read.csv("moviedata.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", dec = ".", na.strings=c(""," ",0))
```

Comment: Try replacing those NA and "" after you read file with read.csv().

Answer (score 0):

In your code `na.strings` argument, you are reading `""`, `" "`, and `0` as NA value. It is what the argument doing.

You should put `0` out and use functions such as `replace_na()` after reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your file

```
movi_data<-read.csv('moviedata.csv',sep=',')
```

How many NA value, use this..

```
table(is.na(movi_data$COLUMN_NAME))
```

find and replace

```
movi_data_after_replace<-replace(movi_data$COLUMN_NAME,is.na(movi_data$COLUMN_NAME),0)
head(movi_data)
```

add to the last column

```
movi_data<-rbind(movi_data,movi_data_after_replace)
head(movi_data)
```

but you have to remove previouse column which contain NA value;using...

```
movi_data<-movi_data[,-COLUMN_INDEX]
```